# Single and multi-dimensional array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a one-dimensional array which contains names 'arrayA' that fills the selectbox and a multi-dimensional array which contains id and names 'arrayB'. I want to display the name if arrayA is equal to arrayB.

For example:

```
$arrayA = array('a','b','c');
```

'a', 'b', 'c' are displayed on selectbox

```
$array2 = array(
    array('id' => 1,'names' => 'a'), 
    array('id' => 2, 'names' => 'd'
    )
);
```

From arrayA 'a' matches with arrayB 'a', so, 'a' will be displayed on selectbox.

Can anybody help on this. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use in_array

```
foreach ($array2 as $key=>$value ){
  if ( in_array($value['names'], $arrayA)){
    echo $value['names'];
  }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: I was looking for this, you got the answer. Thanks for the answer. Will try to implement this with selectbox